Why the statement "the exceptional divisor of blowing up is effective Cartier divisor" is local? ( Stack's Project )
I am trying to understand proof of the Stacks Project Lemma 31.32.4 : https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OF.

Definition 31.32.1. Let $X$ be a scheme. Let $\mathcal{I}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals, and let $Z\subseteq X$ be the closed subscheme corresponding to $\mathcal{I}$. The blowing up of $X$ along $Z$, or the blowing up of $X$ in the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ is the morphism
$$ b: X':=\operatorname{Proj}_{X}(\bigoplus_{n\ge0}\mathcal{I}^n) \to X$$
The exceptional divisor of the blowing up is the inverse image $b^{-1}(Z)$. Sometimes $Z$ is called of the blowing up.

Then Lemma 31.32.4. in the Stacks project states that the exceptional divisor $E=b^{-1}(Z)$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $X'$. And they mentioned that such statement is local, hence we may assume that $X$ affine. I'm trying to check this and don't know why until now. Here an effective Cartier divisor on $S$ is a closed subscheme $D\subseteq S$ whose ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_D \subset \mathcal{O}_S$ is an invertible $\mathcal{O}_S$-module. Also note next Lemma ( Stack's Project Lemma 31.13.2 : https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WQ)

Lemma 31.13.2. Let $S$ be a scheme. Let $D\subset S$ be a closed subscheme. The following are equivalent :

(1) The subscheme $D$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $S$.
(2) For every $x\in D$ there exists an affine open neighborhood $\operatorname{Spec}A=U\subset S$ of $x$ such that $U\cap D=\operatorname{Spec}(A/(f))$ with $f\in A$  a nonzerodivisor.


My first trial is as follows. Let $X=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i := \bigcup_{i\in I}\operatorname{Spec}A_i$ be an affine open cover with $\iota_i:U_i\hookrightarrow X$ the inclusion. Then note that $b|_{b^{-1}(U_i)}^{U_i} : b^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is the blowing up of $U_i$ along $Z\cap U_i$, which can be viewed as closed subscheme of $U_i$, since $b^{-1}(U_i) \cong X'\times_X U_i = \operatorname{Proj}(\bigoplus_{n\ge 0} \mathcal{I}^n) \times_X U_i = \operatorname{Proj}(\iota_i^{*}(\bigoplus_{n\ge 0} \mathcal{I}^n)) = \operatorname{Proj}(\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} (\mathcal{I}|_{U_i})^n) $ and $\mathcal{I}|_{U_i} \subset \mathcal{O}_{U_i}$ is the quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals corresponding to $Z\cap U_i$. So by the reduction assumption each $(b|_{b^{-1}(U_i)}^{U_i})^{-1}(Z \cap U_i)$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $b^{-1}(U_i)$.  Let's denote $D_i := (b|_{b^{-1}(U_i)}^{U_i})^{-1}(Z \cap U_i)$. Then $D:=\bigcup_{i\in I} D_i = b^{-1}(Z) \subseteq X'$, which is closed subscheme. So we want to show that $D$ is effective Cartier divisor on $X'$. And we may use the characterization of effective Cartier divisor-upper lemma 31.13.2.-. And I'm stuck at this step. Can we use Lemma 31.13.2.? How? Can anyone help?

It seems like the only ingredient you're missing is that $b^{-1}(U_i)$ covers the blowup, but that's pretty obvious. IMO, statements like this lemma 31.13.2 obscure things for learners by making clear matters of definition look like nontrivial statements. Do you see why the definition of a Cartier divisor can be checked locally?

O.K.  I am trying to show that $\mathcal{I}{D_i} = \mathcal{I}{D}|{b^{-1}(U_i)}$, where $\mathcal{I}D:=\ker(\mathcal{O}{X'} \to i{D,}\mathcal{O}D)$ and $\mathcal{I}{D_i} := \ker(\mathcal{O}{b^{-1}(U_i)} \to i{D_i,}\mathcal{O}{D_i})$ are corresponding ideal sheaf for $D$ and $D_i$ respectively. Then since each $\mathcal{I}{D_i}$ is invertible $\mathcal{O}_{b^{-1}(U_i)}$-module and $b^{-1}(U_i)$ forms an open covering of $X'$, $\mathcal{I}_D$ is invertible and by definition $D$ is effective Cartier divisor on $X'$. And I am stuck at showing this equality.

Perhaps, $\mathcal{I}D$ can be expressed as the gluing of sheaves $\mathcal{I}{D_i}$? Do you know associated theorem about this kind of issue? Can you give me a hint?

Don’t worry about the closed subschemes. Just work with the ideal sheaves and it’s clearer.

Thank you. I think that key point is next lemma :  Let $Z\subseteq X$ be a closed subscheme with corresponding ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Z \subseteq \mathcal{O}X$. And let $ i : U \hookrightarrow X$ be an open subscheme. Then $\mathcal{I}{Z}|U = \mathcal{I}{Z\cap U} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_U$, which is the ideal sheaf corresponding to the closed subscheme $Z\cap U$ of $U$.

If so, then in our situation, $\mathcal{I}D |{b^{-1}(U_i)} \subseteq \mathcal{O}{b^{-1}(U_i)}$ is the ideal sheaf corresponding to $D \cap b^{-1}(U_i) = b^{-1}(Z) \cap b^{-1}(U_i)= b^{-1}(Z \cap U_i)=D_i$. So $\mathcal{I}D |{b^{-1}(U_i)} = \mathcal{I}{D_i}$ and we are done.

And to show the lemma, I'm trying to show next : Let $(j_Z ,j_Z^{b} ) : Z \hookrightarrow X$ and  $ ( j_{Z\cap U} , j_{Z\cap U}^{b}) : Z\cap U \hookrightarrow U$ be the scheme morphisms. Then for each open $V\subseteq U$, $(j_{Z})^{b}{V} = (j{Z\cap U})^{b}_{V}$? By the definition of the induced reduced subscheme structure on $Z\cap U \subseteq U$? Anyway, if so, then by taking the kernel on both sides, we have $\mathcal{I}_Z|U(V) = \mathcal{I}{Z\cap U}(V)$!

O.K. First, note next lemma :

Lemma . Let $Z\subseteq X$ be a closed subscheme with corresponding ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Z \subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$. And let $i : U \hookrightarrow X$ be an open subscheme. Then $\mathcal{I}_Z|_U = \mathcal{I}_{Z\cap U} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_U$, which is the ideal sheaf corresponding to the closed subscheme $Z\cap U$ of $U$.

Proof. Let $(j_Z,j^b_Z) : Z \hookrightarrow X$ and $(j_{Z\cap U}, j^b_{Z\cap U}) : Z \cap U \hookrightarrow U$ be the morphisms of schemes. Then I guess that maybe for each open $V\subseteq U$, $(j_Z)^{b}_V = ( j_{Z\cap U})^{b}_V$ - by the definition of the induced reduced closed subscheme structure on $Z\cap U \subseteq U$. Then, by taking the kernel on both sides, we have $\mathcal{I}_Z|_U(V) = \mathcal{I}_{Z\cap U}(V)$ .
Second, so, then in our situation, by the lemma, $\mathcal{I}_D|_{b^{-1}(U_i)} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{b^{-1}(U_i)}$ is the ideal sheaf corresponding to $D \cap b^{-1}(U_i) =b^{-1}(Z) \cap b^{-1}(U_i) = b^{-1}(Z\cap U_i) =D_i.$ So $\mathcal{I}_D|_{b^{-1}(U_i)}=\mathcal{I}_{D_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Third, then since each $\mathcal{I}_{D_i}$ is invertible $\mathcal{O}_{b^{-1}(U_i)}$-module ( $\because$ $D_i$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $b^{-1}(U_i)$ as in the question ) and $b^{-1}(U_i)$ forms an open covering of $X'$, $\mathcal{I}_D$ is invertible and by definition $D$ is effective Cartier divisor on $X'$.

-1, you can't reference the induced reduced closed subscheme structure unless you know $Z$ is reduced, which you do not (and cannot) assume here. As per the comments under the main post, work with the ideal sheaves: if an ideal sheaf is locally principal on a cover, it is locally principal.
